# Error with recurring Payment in Paypal API

Tags: php, paypal

I am integrating paypal with my web application developed in PHP. Here is the price structure :

1. $10/month for  2 Month
2. $20/Month for next 6 months
3. $25 per month there after

I have written the following code for it :

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"a1\" value=\"10\"/>\n";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"p1\" value=\"2\"/>\n";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"t1\" value=\"M\"/>\n";

echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"a2\" value=\"20\"/>\n";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"p2\" value=\"6\"/>\n";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"t2\" value=\"M\"/>\n";

echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"a3\" value=\"25\"/>\n";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"p3\" value=\"1\"/>\n";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"t3\" value=\"M\"/>\n";
```

The problem is, with the first 2 trial periods, The paypal statement suggests the following :

1. $10 - 2 Month
2. $20 for next 6 months
3. $25 per month there after

Any idea, what could be the problem with my code here.

Thanks

Comment: Well, I just answered your other question, but now seeing this I realize you're not using Recurring Payments, but rather Standard Subscriptions.  That said, I'm really not sure what you're asking here..??